# Is there a way to log every query with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, arch-linux

My MySQL server has been unusually been using a higher load of CPU. So I looked around how to log each queries and I found a lot of tutorials that were saying the same thing: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/monitor-all-sql-queries-in-mysql/

I followed the tutorial but the log file did not contain any queries. One thing I thought I should mention is that, the `/var/logs/` the folder `mysql` did not exist, so I made the folder and created a log file called `mysql.log` in it.

A little background of my box:

- Arch Linux
- Nginx
- PHP/Ruby/Python/Perl
- MySQL

Comment: Well what do you have in your mysql config?  Do you have an uncommetteded `log =`?

Comment: Setting logging via config needs to restart server to take effect. Otherwise, global variables take effect immediately.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. No originally I did not have an uncommented line for `log = `. So I did add in that part, this is what I put: `log = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log`.

Comment: @Kondybas, I did restart both MySQL and the whole server, and I still got the same results

Comment: recommendations to turn on the general log are not helpful for performance troubleshooting.  Enable the slow query log instead as nojak suggests

Answer (score 1):

By default mysql keep logs in the working directory, usually /var/db/mysql. All you need to enable logging is to set variable `general_log` to "ON". Also, you can set `general_log_file` variable to the desired place.

```
SET @@global.general_log = 1;
SET @@global.general_log_file = '/where/to/store/log/file.txt';
```

Comment: I am not able to find neither 'general_log' in `my.cnf` or the folder `/var/db/mysql/`. I did a select on both of those variables, `select @@global.general_log;` => 1, and `select @@global.general_log_file;` => `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log`.

Comment: You have to SET, not SELECT

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to select the variable and see what is currently stored?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: @chudapati09 You should use `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log%'` to view the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Slow Query Log option.

[You can find detailed information on dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html)

Comment: This is a better option than the general log for performance issues.